# Is it possible to set the SharedPreference in the BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to generate notification using `BroadcastReceiver` and need to save some data in the `BroadcastReceiver` class.

So, I used `SharedPreference`. But not able to save data inSharedPreference`.

```
  SharedPreferences pref_date;
  public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
  pref_date = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    _ed = pref_date.edit();
    String t="hello";
    _ed.putString(_date,t);
    _ed.putString(flag,"0");
    _ed.commit();
```

Comment: Yes, you can access shared preferences from BR, this is processed in the UI main thread. What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error but values are not storing to shared preference

Comment: those shared preference values am using only in the BR.nowhere else in the application

Comment: Ok, seems fine to me. Why do you think the data isn't saved?

Comment: @aga values stored in shared preference but the problem is when I take more than one variable last value will be assigned to other variables too. EX: in my code _date variable modified to 0 when flag sets to 0

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell w/o looking into the source code, but most possibly you forgot to invoke the `Editor`'s `apply()` or `commit()` method, like so:

```
mSharedPreferences.edit().putInt("some_int", 0).apply();
```

Comment: I have posted my code which i used in BR.Please have a look on it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [SharepPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is just a kind of file that has key-value pairs to store and retrieve. You can access it from anywhere within the application. Even from the Services created by your application.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html), this is how you should write to your SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("yourKey", "stringToSave");
editor.commit();
```

And this is how you read:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String defaultValue = "defaultValue";
String yourSavedString = sharedPref.getString("yourKey", defaultValue);
```

This is a working copy/paste example. Keep in mind that `"yourKey"` is used to identify your value, since SharedPreferences is key/value pair, so they have to match both when you read and write.